# Dynamic Header Of user control

Tags: c#

I have develop a user control and i am loading it dynamically through .aspx page.
I have develop an XML and had converted it into hash table for faster searching.
The hash table contains the page name and the respective header.
I am using that hash table to load the header of .aspx page dynamically.
Now, i want that when the user control is called its header is also set dynamically by searching that hash table.

I have tried a lot but the problem which i am facing is that i am not able to trap the requested user control path at runtime.......
pls let me know if u have another solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

If this XML contains HTML that should be displayed as Header, just use the Xml control.